# Inserting & Reading JSON data to Scope variable AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, api

Depending on user input I need to make API calls which then returns me JSON Data.

```
$scope.citys = [];    
$http.get($scope.apiURL+newCity).then(function(response) {
            $scope.citys.push(response.data);
});
```

So after lets say two such requests I have a bunch of JSON data in my citys array.

When I try to access it however I receive nothing :(

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in citys">{{citys.data.city.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, regarding what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `{{citys.data.city.name}}` should be `{{data.city.name}}` i think.

Comment: Yep. You're right. I only just saw it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:
{{citys.data.city.name}} should be {{data.city.name}}

Since your using ng-repeat="data in citys", angular will loop through 'citys' assigning each value to 'data'.